# Per diem and equal company benefits

Tags: job-change, travel, benefits, taxes, equality

I accepted a full-time job in august working in a city 25 miles from where I lived. Key word "lived". The project manager was well organized fair and provided us with water, snacks and sunscreen for each day. We are often outside all day. I was asked by the owner of the company if I would like to work in another nearby city on a different project with a different team and I would recive a $1 more in my hourly pay. I accepted and during this time I also became homeless unable to cover the cost of rent, phone bill , car insurance and gas expenses as I'm paid weekly.  Most of The team on the new project are from "out of town" and are provided a  Orel room during the 2 weeks of work.  Recently we started another new project in another nearby city but since I'm homeless it's cheaper for me to stay in the city we just finished the project in but it's much farther than the new project city.  I am the only one left on the team that is "local" but I told the owner my living situation changed and I haven't been able to find anyplace to live 'would it be possible to also get a room' she pretty much said no.  I'm curious how an employer is able to get away with not reimbursing me for meals, tax me on my gas reimbursement (.25cents) expenses, not provide any water while I'm using my personal car and work over 30 miles away from where I used to live and have no place to store my lunch in a fridge no break area etc.

I'm only 1 of three people on a team of 6 that has a car and I'm the only person required to meet to "sign in " and "sign out" so when I'm late because of traffic or have a doctor appointment I do not get my full 40 hours but the rest of the boys always seem to complete their hours on their own schedules. I have no idea how everyone else is doing yet everyone else is updated on my work.  My biggest gripe is 40 hours and no per diem to help with food and tax on the little bit of gas $12 I get daily for driving over 70-80 miles a day in my car from the city I can afford a motel room when Or if I can afford it.

Is this legal to offer a motel room to the guys but not merge only girl?

Comment: What country/state? What terms were discussed when you accepted the project change?

Comment: An employer is not required, or expected, to reimburse ordinary costs of living. Commuting is one of those. Figuring out how to bring a bag lunch that doesn't require refrigeration, or make other suitable arrangements,  is another. Per diem is never offered for your primary office, not on business trips or under special circumstances such as a time-honored relocation allowance. If you can't afford the costs of holding this job, maybe it isn't the right job at this time.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - As it mentions sunscreen it cannot be Scotland. We have not seen the Sun for months

Answer (score 5):

You need to sort out your personal life, the employer is not responsible for it. You took the job and you should have done the math and worked out your requirements at that point. If you're not making enough to live on then you're in the wrong job. Motel rooms are expensive, consider hostels, backpackers or something cheaper.

It doesn't pay to be fussy when you're broke, and it's never a good idea to live hand to mouth if you can avoid it. It's just treading water trying to survive but not getting ahead. Look for replacement job, and a second job. There are high paying menial jobs available in many places. I made a lot of money cleaning offices at night at one point in my work career.